# AngularJs Separating Results into Divs by column value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logic, resultset

I have been struggling to figure out the logic on how to display my results into separate divs in this case bootstrap col-md-4's. It is for a chat messaging app that i'm attempting to build. There is rooms and messages I want each room to only display it's messages grouped together into divs.

My results($scope.messages) look like:

```
messages = [
    {"room_id":1,"message_id":2,"message_content":"hiiii","message_time":"2015-11-28 23:22:57","user_name":"Aaaa1aa"},
    {"room_id":1,"message_id":1,"message_content":"hi there","message_time":"2015-11-28 23:22:40","user_name":"aaaa2aa"},
    {"room_id":2,"message_id":3,"message_content":"hyyy","message_time":"2015-11-28 23:23:07","user_name":"Guest"},
    {"room_id":2,"message_id":4,"message_content":"aaaaa","message_time":"2015-11-28 23:23:20","user_name":"aaaa2aa"}
];
```

I want to display each results set grouped by the room_id column so when repeating through the data this set would look like so

```
<div class="col-md-4"> Room Id - 1
aaaa2aa - hi there
Aaaa1aa - hiiii
</div>

<div class="col-md-4"> Room Id - 2
Guest - hyyy
aaaa2aa - aaaaa
</div>
```

I thought something like this *might* work after trying several other options but it is not providing any results.

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="data in messages">
<div ng-repeat="data in data[$index]">

{{data.user_name}}
{{data.message_content}}

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

This is what worked for me, but you must first add the module filter as an dependency:

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="data in messages | groupBy: 'room_id'">
    {{data[$index].room_id}}
<div ng-repeat="data in data">
    {{data.user_name}}
    {{data.message_content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` to group the results:

```
(k, v) in messages | groupBy: 'room_id'
```

Another solution would be to use `filter`:

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="data in messages | filter: '{'room_id': 2}'"> //show only items with room_id set to 2 and so on

</div>
```

However, this method will be repetitive and redundant.

Comment: Thats what I thought as well, but for some reason it is providing this error and not returning any results: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=groupByFilterProvider

Comment: Both solutions give the dependency error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=groupByFilterProvider

Comment: I've got it, I guess groupBy does not come standard with angular and I had to add the filter module and then use the groupBy clause. Ill add a snippet to my question with the final working solution. Ill mark this as correct since it guided me down the exact path I needed to go!